# path error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, celery

Project like below

```
server
├── celery.py
├── tasks.py
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from sys import path 
from .celery import app_celery
from time import sleep


@app_celery.task
def my_func():
    sleep(5)
    print("Process finished")
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app_celery = Celery('server',
             broker='redis://',
             backend='redis://',
             include=['server.tasks'])

app_celery.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_celery.start()
```

`celery -A  server worker -l info` starts well, make a test like below and it was perfect

```
$ ipython
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from server.tasks import my_func                                                                                                                     

In [2]: my_func.delay()                                                                                                                                      
Out[2]: <AsyncResult: 39a21329-0e80-4f6e-ac08-536832414756>
```

I want to add a script `test.py` under `server`

test.py

```
from tasks import my_func

my_func.delay()
```

When I run `python test.py` under `server`, it reports

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tasks import my_func
  File "/xxx/server/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .celery import app_celery
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `__init__.py` file inside your server directory. This file can be empty.

Python only allows relative imports in regular packages. A regular package is defined as a directory that contains a `__init__.py` file.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, it still reports the same error

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Did you type the file name correctly? It's two underscores on both ends.

Comment: I check it again and yes.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Try renaming `celery.py` into something else. It is conflicting with the actual Celery package and might be one of the causes of the problem.

Comment: The error remains the same when I change `celery.py` to `celery_1.py` and made other relative changes. (  `from .celery_1 import app_celery
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`)